# TCPDF sticker generation for 2X6 stickers using codeigniter/core php

Tags: tcpdf

Need to create 12 stickers(2X6) using TCPDF and codeigniter/core php in A4 size format.

Following is the code snippet in pastebin
http://pastebin.com/kbevqtfX

the desired result should be like
[image: http://imgur.com/NMpUYNw]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 

```
    $top_margin = 32;
    $side_margin = 16;
    $vertical_pitch = 85;
    $horizantal_pitch = 350;
    $label_height = 44;
    $label_width = 100;
    $width = 212;
    $height = 315;
    $resolution = array($height, $width);

    echo "<table>";
    for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
    $txt = '<tr style="width:100%"><td style="margin-top:'.$top_margin.'px;margin-left:'.$side_margin.'px;width:'.$horizantal_pitch.'px;height:'.$vertical_pitch.'px;float:left">Card Ref No: 10166<br>Abhilasha S Mishra<br>Golden Encalve, KVMR, Block C, Near Manipal, Bangalore, 560034, Karnataka, TEL: 234567897</td>
    <td style="margin-top:'.$top_margin.'px;margin-left:'.$side_margin.'px;width:'.$horizantal_pitch.'px;height:'.$vertical_pitch.'px;float:left">Card Ref No: 10166<br>Abhilasha S Mishra<br>Golden Encalve, KVMR, Block C, Near Manipal, Bangalore, 560034, Karnataka, TEL: 234567897</td></tr>'; 

    echo $txt;
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

?>
**use this instead**

Answer (score 1):

I have found the better way to create these stickers. I have replaced the div from the html part and used table instead of it. The code snippet is in pastebin
http://pastebin.com/0sryTihK